# How do you supress the user response in a cmd set prompt?

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I want to have an authentication prompt for my batch file. So I used `set /P` like this:

```
set /P password=Enter password:
```

But the problem is that I have to suppress the user output like when using `net user anyuser *`. Is there a way to do that in Windows 10?

I tried `set /P password="Enter password:" >NUL` but it didn't work.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The tools you are using don't support that. Use a correct tool.

Comment: What do you mean with a correct tool? Which are those tools?